# Zoom on jqplot not working , also unable to plot data points

Tags: jquery, graph, jqplot

I am using `jqplot` for plotting a graph .Below is the code :

```
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    // For these examples, don't show the to image button.
    $.jqplot._noToImageButton = true;




    var ticks = ["8/25/2008","1/22/2009","6/20/2009","7/20/2009","10/20/2009","6/20/2010","2/20/2011"] ; 



  goog = [[56, 60, 79,20,34,67]];


  var plot1 = $.jqplot(id, goog, {
      title: title,
      series: [{
          label: series,
          neighborThreshold: -1
      }],



       axesDefaults: {                                                       
          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
          tickOptions:{
            angle: -30,
            fontSize: '10pt'

          }
      }, 


      seriesDefaults: {
          showMarker:true,                      
          pointLabels: { show:false }        
        },

      axes: {
          xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
              min:'Sun Aug 24 16:00:00 2008',
              max:'Sun Jan 21,16:00:00 2009',
              numberTicks: 7,
             // tickInterval: '4 months',
             ticks : ticks,


              tickOptions:{formatString:'%#c'},

          },
          yaxis: {
              tickOptions:{formatString:'%.2f'}
          }
      },
      cursor:{
        show: true,
        zoom:true,
        showTooltip:true
      }
  });

  $('.button-reset').click(function() { plot1.resetZoom() });
```

These are the issues that I am facing

1. The data points are not plotted , so I get a blank graph .
2. On zooming , only Y-Axis changes and X-axis remains the same .
3. `CanvasAxisTickRenderer` is not working so I dont get `ticks` with specified angle.
4. `min` and `max` for Xaxis is also not working , the graph itself plots the `ticks` taking the first and the last value in `ticks` array.

I am new to `jquery` so please dont mind for a such long question, any help is highly appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you loaded all the plugins that are needed ?(jqplot.cursor.min.js, jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js, jqplot.pointLabels.min.js, jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js...)

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic Yes i have loaded all the plugins and there is no error related to a particular JS not found ,as shown by FireBug , that is all the plugins are loaded with correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data aren't well declared, you need to specify an array of [x,y] values fr each point. Your goog variables became :

goog = [[["8/25/2008",56], ["1/22/2009",60], ["6/20/2009",79],["7/20/2009",20],["10/20/2009",34],["6/20/2010",67],["2/20/2011",42]]];

PS : I have also added a new value in goog in order to have 7 points as 7 ticks.

Comment: Yes , according to the examples on jqplot website , they have used array of [x,y] for each point , but I am working on bar graphs too so was thinking of making a generalized format for input , that is different arrays for [x] and [y] mapped with index. Anyway I tried using [x,y] , and now it's working fine . Thanks a lot for your valuable respone , highly appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

It's not zooming on the x-axis because you have specified the "ticks" option on the x-axis. I'm having the same issue. Seems to me this is a bug.  It should work as expected even when I set the ticks (as an initial "un-zoomed" value).

Comment: This answer enabled me to find the complete fix when I ran into the same issue.  While it's true that enabling ticks on the x-axis does seem to stop zooming from working, I also needed to remove the inclusion of jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js from my page's markup.

After that, zooming is working as it is meant to.